# Menu click function doesn’t work first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Next function doesn't work first time when menu item is clicked but works after that. It is located just before `</body>` tag. It puts the "current" selector in the selected menu item. Any idea why it doesn't work first time?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  (function($, NAME) {
    var nav = $('ul#primary-menu');
    nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {

      var $this = $(this),
        $targetContent;

      $this.closest('[id="primary-menu"]').find('a').removeClass('current');
      $this.addClass('current');

    });

  })(jQuery);

</script>
```

```html
<ul id="primary-menu" class="main-nav underline-decoration l-to-r-line outside-item-remove-margin" role="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-39 first"><a href='#etusivu' data-level='1' class='menu-item'><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Etusivu</span></span></a></li> <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47"><a href='#palvelut' data-level='1' class='menu-item'><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Palvelut</span></span></a></li> <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-48"><a href='#tuotteet' data-level='1' class='menu-item'><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Tuotteet</span></span></a></li> <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-49"><a href='#referenssit' data-level='1' class='menu-item'><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Referenssit</span></span></a></li> <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-50"><a href='#ajankohtaista' data-level='1' class='menu-item'><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Ajankohtaista</span></span></a></li> <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href='#yhteystiedot' data-level='1' class='menu-item'><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Yhteystiedot</span></span></a></li> </ul>
```

Comment: Now it has been added.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to remove the class 'current'  from other items and add it to clicked item you can do it like this:

PS: Don't forget to include the 'jQuery' file before the script.

```js
$(function () {

      var navItems = $('#primary-menu a');
      navItems.on('click', function(){

          navItems.removeClass('current'); // remove the class from all #primary-menu a items
          $(this).addClass('current'); // add the class to the clicked item


      });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu">
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Warp your code inside the `document.ready`

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
  (function($, NAME) {
    var nav = $('ul#primary-menu');
    nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {

      var $this = $(this),
        $targetContent;

      $this.closest('[id="primary-menu"]').find('a').removeClass('current');
      $this.addClass('current');

    });
})
  })(jQuery);

</script>
```